# How to store changed array into object property while using splice()

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux, react-redux

I am writing a switch statement for a reducer and would like to update the spliced version of a given property when returning the overall object.

How can I properly store the updated array into the object?
Here is a function that simulates the problem:

```
const newData = {
  id: 1, 
  url: "url", 
  query: "mangoes",
  title: "this title"
}

const target = [
  {
    id: 0, 
    url: "", 
    query: "mangoes",
    title: "old title"
  }
]

const switchCase = () => {
    return {
        targetProp: target.splice(0, 1, newData)
    }
}
```

The returned object has the initial unchanged target as the "targetProp" rather than an updated one

Comment: `splice` returns the removed elements, and mutates the target array.

Comment: Is there a work around when using `splice` or do I need to use a different function?

Comment: Shouldn't you be avoiding mutation?

Comment: well, I agree with @CertainPerformance you should avoid mutation. but if you are ok with mutation, you can just do target.splice(0, 1, newData); return {targetProp: target};

Comment: Essentially, I have a condition that decides whether or not to either replace or add the target object onto the "targetProp" array. Would avoiding mutation mean that I have to write a reducer that filters out the data that I want after allowing all data to be added?

Comment: Is it as simple as `target.splice(0, 1, newData); return target;`?